# Google App Engine : How to choose regular expression for app.yaml

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

For example : I have sub-application name blog. So, when user want to go front page of blog, he will go : `localhost/blog` and so the regular expression for this link is :

```
-url: /blog
script:blog.app
```

but, for example, in this application, there are some other links : `localhost/blog/X` such as  : `localhost/blog/signup` or `localhost/blog/signin`..... And above regular expression will not fit. If I want to use those links, I must change again:

```
-url: /blog/.*
script:blog.app
```

But this regular expression cannot fit for `localhost/blog`. Of course, I can combine those regular expression together, but I think It's too handy. Can I have one regular expression and fit both.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh. I have found on google that regular expression for this `app.yaml` is same as others language I used such as Perl or Java Regular Expression Library. So, here is my regular expression for anyone who need answer for above answer :

```
- url: /blog(/.*)*
  script: blog.app
```

Explain: (character)* : mean it can be have those characters or not will fit for above regular expression.

So, `/blog`, `/blog/` or `/blog/signup` or `/blog/signin`... will fit.

@: Sorry if my question looks like spam :)

Comment: /blog(/.*)? might be a clearer regex, although functionally equivalent